# Difference between the annotations @GetMapping and @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-4

What's the difference between `@GetMapping` and `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)`?
 I've seen in some Spring Reactive examples, that 
`@GetMapping` was used instead of `@RequestMapping`

Answer (score 250, accepted):

`@GetMapping` is a composed annotation that acts as a shortcut for `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)`.

`@GetMapping` is the newer annotaion. 
It supports consumes

Consume options are :

**consumes = "text/plain"

 consumes = {"text/plain", "application/*"}**

For Further details see:
[GetMapping Annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/GetMapping.html)

or read:
[request mapping variants](http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/request-mapping-variants/)

**RequestMapping supports consumes as well**

GetMapping we can apply only on method level and RequestMapping annotation we can apply on class level and as well as on method level

Comment: `@GetMapping` supports `consumes` - http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/GetMapping.html#consumes--

Comment: RequestMapping supports consumes as well: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#consumes--

Answer (score 26):

As you can see [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/GetMapping.html):

> Specifically, `@GetMapping` is a composed annotation that acts as a
>   shortcut for `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)`.
>
> Difference between `@GetMapping` & `@RequestMapping`
>
> `@GetMapping` supports the `consumes` attribute like
>   `@RequestMapping`.

Comment: Good news!  As of 4/2017, on the Spring web page you linked to, GetMapping *does* now support 'consumes' and the usual RequestMapping attributes.  Probably Spring added those after your post.

Answer (score 21):

`@RequestMapping` is a class level

`@GetMapping` is a method-level

With sprint Spring 4.3. and up things have changed. Now you can use @GetMapping on the method that will handle the http request. The class-level @RequestMapping specification is refined with the (method-level)@GetMapping annotation

Here is an example:

```
@Slf4j
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/orders")/* The @Request-Mapping annotation, when applied
                            at the class level, specifies the kind of requests 
                            that this controller handles*/  

public class OrderController {

@GetMapping("/current")/*@GetMapping paired with the classlevel
                        @RequestMapping, specifies that when an 
                        HTTP GET request is received for /order, 
                        orderForm() will be called to handle the request..*/

public String orderForm(Model model) {

model.addAttribute("order", new Order());

return "orderForm";
}
}
```

Prior to Spring 4.3, it was `@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)`

*Extra reading from a book authored by Craig Walls*
[image: Extra reading from a book authored by Craig Walls]

Comment: @RequestMapping can also be applied to method.

Comment: Yes, it can be. However, @GetMapping is more succinct and specific to the HTTP method that it targets.

Comment: ZhaoGang makes a good point. Your answer is wrong. You can argue that the way you do things is a GOOD CONVENTION. But doesn't change the fact that your answer, as currently written, is wrong.

Comment: @KANJICODER why WOULD you ever want to use  "@RequestMapping" more than once in a controller,  xxxxController.java file.??? why.. Think about future maintainers.... other people too!

Answer (score 14):

**Short answer:**

There is no difference in semantic.

> Specifically, @GetMapping is a **composed annotation that acts as a
>   shortcut** for @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET).

**Further reading:**

`RequestMapping` can be used at class level:

> This annotation can be used both at the class and at the method level.
>   In most cases, at the method level applications will prefer to use one
>   of the HTTP method specific variants @GetMapping, @PostMapping,
>   @PutMapping, @DeleteMapping, or @PatchMapping.

while `GetMapping` only applies to method:

> Annotation for mapping HTTP GET requests onto specific handler
>   methods.

---

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/GetMapping.html

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html

Answer (score 2):

---

```
                         `@RequestMapping` since 2.5
```

---

=> Can handle all HTTP methods

=> Applicable to class and method

=> Can be used as a substitute of `@Controller` and `@RestController`, If we use it
along with `@Component`.

---

```
                        `@GetMapping` since 4.3
```

---

=> Can handle only GET method of HTTP

=> Applicable to method only

`@GetMapping` is a specific type of `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)`. Both supports consumes

Answer (score -1):

1. `@RequestMapping` supports consumes even with method=GET, while @GetMapping doesn't supports consumes.
2. @RequestMapping is Method & Type level annotation, while @GetMapping is a Method level annotation

**Other than that @GetMapping is same as @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)**

Answer (score -1):

1. @GetMapping is the shortcut for @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
2. @RequestMapping is a class level
3. @GetMapping is a method-level

4)The @RequestMapping annotation is used to map web requests to specific handler classes and functions. This annotations key advantage is that it may be used on both the controller class and methods.

5)It is always advised to be specific while declaring @RequestMapping on the controller methods as in most mapping handler classes, @Getmapping is not used.