# Request method 'GET' not supported Spring Booth with Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am building a very simple crud app using Spring boot, Jpa and Thymeleaf, but I am stuck at a "Request method 'GET' not supported" problem. I get this error whenever I want to access the /add page through which I can add a new student. The snippets associated with this error are as below:

Thymeleaf form:

```
<h1>Form</h1>
<form action="#" th:action="@{/add}" th:object="${addStudent}" 
   method="post">
    <p>Full name: <input type="text" th:field="*{fname}" /></p>
    <p>Major: <input type="text" th:field="*{major}" /></p>

    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
</form>
```

Controller addNewStudentMethod

```
@PostMapping("/add")
public String addNewStudent( @ModelAttribute StudentEntity studentEntity, Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("addStudent",studentRepository.save(studentEntity) );
    return "/allstudents";
}
```

The error I get:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Request method 'GET' not supported
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some issues with how you have it set up.  What you may want is:

```
@GetMapping("/add")
public String addNewStudent(Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("studentEntity", new StudentEntity()); //create a new bean so that your form can bind the input fields to it
    return "add"; //let's say add.html this is the name of your form
}

@PostMapping("/add")
public String addNewStudent( @ModelAttribute StudentEntity studentEntity, Model model) {

  //call any service methods to do any processing here
  studentRepository.save(studentEntity);
  return "redirect:/allstudents";  //this would be your confirmation page
}
```

Your `add.html` form would have something like:

```
<form th:object="${studentEntity}" th:action="@{/add}" method="post" action="allstudents.html">
<!-- input fields here --->
</form>
```

Note that the `th:object` is what you added to the model in the `@GetMapping` method.

Comment: Thanks, that works ! However, I would like to know if there is a way to combine both the Get and Post methods into one? As in using RequestMapping, for example.

Comment: Not sure that I understand.  One method is responding with the page the user is seeking and the other method is getting called when the user clicks the submit button, based on the method="post" on the form.  So you want both behaviors in one method?

Comment: Note that `@GetMapping` and `@PostMapping` are actually shortcuts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39077787/difference-between-the-annotations-getmapping-and-requestmappingmethod-requ

Answer (score 2):

In your controller you only have a method which has mapped to `POST` request "/add". You have to have a `GET` request mapped to a different method OR change the `@PostMapping("/add")` to `@RequestMapping("/add")`.

Please note:

`@PostMapping` is for mapping `POST` request only.
`@GetMapping` is for mapping `GET` request only.
`@RequestMapping` maps all request types

Comment: I did that and it seems to work only if I replace return "/allstudents" by return "/add" which then takes me to the form to submit a new record. I originally put return "/allstudents" because I would like to return to the allstudents page after I successfully submit the form? Any suggestions? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

change your Controller methods's `@PostMapping("/any-url")` to either `@GetMapping("/any-url")` or `@RequestMapping("/any-url")`

In simple words, change your above controller's method to

```
@RequestMapping("/add")
public String addNewStudent( @ModelAttribute StudentEntity studentEntity, Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("addStudent",studentRepository.save(studentEntity) );
    return "/allstudents";
}
```

Comment: I did that and it seems to work only if I replace return "/allstudents" by return "/add" which then takes me to the form to submit a new record. I originally put return "/allstudents" because I would like to return to the allstudents page after I successfully submit the form? Any suggestions? Thank you