# What is the difference between @RequestMapping and @PostMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations

in the below example, I am trying to undersatnd the difference between @RequestMapping and @PostMapping. 
For @RequestMapping:

when i do the POST request: 
    http://localhost:8085/call1/initparam1?val=1111 via postman, it executes correctly.
but when its is proceeded by by GET request
    http://localhost:8085/call1/getparam1

i do not get 1111 as a result.

For @PostMapping, when i do the POST request: 
    http://localhost:8085/call1/initparam2/1999 via postman, it executes correctly.
but when its is proceeded by by GET request
    http://localhost:8085/call1/getparam1

i do not get 1999 as a result.

please explain to me what is the difference between using both annotations, as i spent time googling and researching but i could not figure out why the first example is not working.

**Controller1**

```
@Controller
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping("/call1")
public class Call1 {

public String str = "inti";

@RequestMapping(value = "/initparam1", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void initparam1(@RequestParam(value = "val") String val) {
    this.str = val;
}

@PostMapping(value = "/initparam2/{val}")
public void initparam2(@PathVariable String val) {
    this.str = val;
}

@RequestMapping("/getparam1")
@ResponseBody
public String getParam1() {
    return this.str;
}
}
```

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong but what I understand is your first example is **not working** and second is **working correctly**. Because in both the case you have written **'I do not get...'**

Comment: Both the scenarios are setting and return the respective values in GET request. I have checked with Spring Boot 2.1.6 version.

Comment: https://howtodoinjava.com/spring5/webmvc/controller-getmapping-postmapping/

Comment: RequestMapping vs specific Get/Post mapping discussed here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39077787/difference-between-the-annotations-getmapping-and-requestmappingmethod-requ

Answer (score 18):

From the [`@PostMapping`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PostMapping.html) docs :

> Specifically, @PostMapping is a composed annotation that acts as a shortcut for @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST).

So it is only convenience annotation that is more "verbose" and indicates that method annotated with it is used for handling POST HTTP requests.

I have just checked your controller methods with `2.1.4` spring boot version and your scenarios work as expected so there has to be something wrong in your configuration or the way you are sending requests.

Comment: but did you realized the other part of the quest. please. using the POSTMAPPING gives me the expected result but the REQUESTMAPPING gives unexpected result

Comment: I have just checked your set up and it works as expected, both endpoints set the value of your String.